# How to insert watermark in image by gm (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, image, graphicimage

I need to insert watermark to your images using gm.

```
gm('/path/to/input-image.jpg')
.draw(['image Over 0,0 0,0 /path/to/half-transparent-watermark-image.png'])
.write('/path/to/output-image.jpg', function(e){
 console.log(e||'done'); // What would you like to do here?
});
```

But have error message: Error: Command failed: convert: Non-conforming drawing primitive definition `/path/to/half-transparent-watermark-image.png''@ draw.c / DrawImage / 3124. How can I insert the watermark?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should put the image named 「*half-transparent-watermark-image.png*」 on path 「*/path/to/*」, I just try your code but using my own image name, it's work.

Answer (score 0):

gm requires additional quoting:

```
.draw(['image over 0,0 0,0 "/path/to/file.png"'])
```